# counting function in modular arithmetics

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

Call $a>b>1$  two coprime integers, and choose $ a > m \ge 0$.
Denote by  $[n]_a$  the minimal positive representative of  $n\; (mod\; a)$;
Determine
$$A(a,b,m) = \sum_{i=1}^{a} \left|\{j\:|\: a\ge j>i \mbox{ and } [bj + bm]_a > [bi + bm]_a \}\right|$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: This problem comes from low dimensional topology, I was able to solve some easy cases (for instance when b = 1), but not the general case. Since some quantities derived from these A functions behave in a somehow erratic manner I was wondering if A admits a closed form.